# Quotient ring of the ring of integers of an algebraic number field and its fraction field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be an arbitrary algebraic number field. We know that the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is $K$ which is  always isomorphic to some $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$. $\mathcal{O}_K$ also has dimension one so I was wondering if something similar might be said of $\mathcal{O}_K/m$, for any non-zero prime(=maximal) ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$? Is it isomorphic to some quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The quotient by a maximal ideal is already a field. (And the statement is that any *nonzero* prime ideal is maximal.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan inserted the non-zero part I forgot about. I realise that it's already a field, what I was wondering is if it could have a similar characterisation in terms $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: It's a finite field. What do you know about the structure of finite fields?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$ for some prime $p$ and an irreducible monic polynomial $(f(x))$, right?

Comment: Actually this question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334980/quotient-of-the-ring-of-integers-of-a-number-field-by-a-prime-ideal) gives everything that I need to know. I just found it. Should I delete my question? I am not sure, I haven't been here long.

Comment: It's usually fine as long as no one's given an answer yet.