# Algebraic number field quotiented by a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K$ be a number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers, $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ a prime ideal, and $p \in \mathbb{N}$ the rational prime lying below $\mathfrak{p}$.

I find myself unable to either prove or disprove the following:

> (i) Is it true that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$?
>
> (ii) Is it true that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p} \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, where $n:= [K:\mathbb{Q}]$?

These questions have come up in my attempt to prove the existence of the Frobenius element in the Galois group of an extension of algebraic number fields.

I am aware of the existence of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334980/quotient-of-the-ring-of-integers-of-a-number-field-by-a-prime-ideal), but it is not what I am looking for. In particular, it only considers quadratic number fields.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $O_K$

- The first step is to prove that $\mathfrak{p}$ contains an integer, namely the constant coefficient of the minimal polynomial of any of its elements.
- Since $\mathfrak{p}$ contains an integer then $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$ has finite characteristic, since it is an integral domain it has characteristic $p$ prime.
- Since $K$ is a $n$ dimensional $\Bbb{Q}$- vector space and $O_K$ is a subgroup then $O_K/pO_K$ has at most $p^n$ elements, ie. $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$ is a finite group thus a finite integral domain thus a finite field. Being also a $\Bbb{F}_p$ vector space it has $p^k$ elements.
- Up to isomorphism there is only one finite field with $p^k$ elements (the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x\in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$) thus $O_K/\mathfrak{p}\cong \Bbb{F}_{p^k}$.

Comment: Many thanks. What is the $k$ introduced in your third bullet?

Comment: The dimension of $O_K/\mathfrak{p}$ as a $\Bbb{F}_p$-vector space. If can be any integer between $1$ and $n$ (because $O_K/(p)$ has $p^n$ elements). If $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois then $k$ divides $n$. In general $k$ divides $[L:\Bbb{Q}]$ where $L$ is the Galois closure of $K/\Bbb{Q}$. Usually $k$ is denoted $f(\mathfrak{p}/p)$.